# Remote GDB session "Command Aborted"

Tags: c++11, gdb, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi3, gdbserver

I am using VSCode, writing code for a RPi. I have almost gotten it set up to use the integrated debugger, however, I am running into an issue where GDB says `Command Aborted`

Here is the ouput from the debug window in VSCode

```
<License and whatnot from GDB>
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Reading /lib/ld-linux.so.3 from remote target...
Reading /lib/ld-linux.so.3 from remote target...
Reading /lib/f72fb00897d4f06093d6f0451c9ca7d1f6e14c.debug from remote target...
Reading /lib/.debug/f72fb00897d4f06093d6f0451c9ca7d1f6e14c.debug from remote target...
0x76fce9e0 in ?? () from target:/lib/ld-linux.so.3
Loaded 'target:/lib/ld-linux.so.3'. Symbols loaded.
ERROR: Command aborted.
```

Here is the script I am using to setup gdbserver on the RPi (with the variable names excluded to protect my privacy).

```
ssh \
  -L$port:localhost:$port $user@$remote \
  "zsh -l -c './kill-gdbserver.sh && cd msat-pi* && ./waf && gdbserver :$port ./build/examples/onewire/onewire'"
```

And the relevant configuration from my `launch.json`

```
{
    "name": "1w-Remote",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/examples/onewire/onewire",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:8081",
    "targetArchitecture": "arm",
    "args": [],
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb-arm",
    "preLaunchTask": "waf-build",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "linux": {
      "MIMode": "gdb"
    },
    "osx": {
      "MIMode": "gdb"
    },
    "windows": {
      "MIMode": "gdb"
    }
  }
```

If I manually setup GDB locally, I get the same output, except, no `Command Aborted` message. I can then `continue`, which acts as I would expect (my program crashes on an unhandled exception).

Is there some way I can avoid this `Command Aborted` issue, or should I open an issue on the VSCode git?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have compiled your program without debugging information. Compile it with -g compiler and linker option.

Comment: Nope, here is a verbose output from my build script

`$ ./waf build -v`
`Waf: Entering directory /home/gavinu/Documents/M-SAT/msat-pi-interface/build`
`[0/4] Compiling src/onewire/onewire.cpp`
`12:55:51 runner ['arm-linux-gnueabi-g++', '-Wall', '-g', '-std=c++14', '-I../include/i2c', '-I../../include/i2c', '-I../include/onewire', '-I../../include/onewire', '-I../include/usart', '-I../../include/usart', '../src/onewire/onewire.cpp', '-c', '-o<edited out for privacy>/msat-pi-interface/build/src/onewire/onewire.cpp.1.o']`

Comment: I have it building a library and then an example using said library.
`[2/4] Linking build/lib/libonewire.a`
`14:06:11 runner ['arm-linux-gnueabi-ar', 'rcs', 'lib/libonewire.a', 'src/onewire/onewire.cpp.1.o']`
`[3/4] Linking build/examples/onewire/onewire`
`14:06:14 runner ['arm-linux-gnueabi-g++', '-g', '-fPIC', 'examples/onewire.cpp.2.o', '-o/<privacy edit>/msat-pi-interface/build/examples/onewire/onewire', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Llib', '-lonewire', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-lpthread', '-ldl']`

Comment: Can you change `"stopAtEntry": true` and see if it stops when you enter main?

Comment: I have, no change.

Comment: i have a similar problem